# Передать значение в form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Article $article){

    $article->update($request->except('slug', 'image_path'));
    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
        $image = $request->file('image_path');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

        $article->image_path = $new_name;
        $article->save();
    }
    $article->categories()->detach();
    if ($request->has('categories')) {
        $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
    }
    $user=auth()->user();
    if($user->role_id == 1){
        return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
    }else if($user->role_id == 3){
        return redirect()->route('writer.article.index');
    }else if ($user->role_id == 2){
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Update!');
    }
}

public function edit(Article $article){
    $user=auth()->user();
        return view('user.edit',[
            'article' => $article,
            'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home/edit/{id}','Controller_Article_parents@edit', function () {
   return view('/home/edit', [
    'article' => Article::find($id)
]);
 })->name('edit');


Route::get('/home/update/','Controller_Article_parents@update', function () {
  return view('/home');
 })->name('update');
```

edit

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
{{ csrf_field() }}

{{-- Form include --}}

<img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">

   @include('partials.form')

<input type="hidden" name="modified_by" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
```

blade вывода статей

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($articles_suggest_user as $article)
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('edit', $article)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Когда я перехожу по  ссылки `<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('edit', $article)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>`   то форма всегда пустая ..  `<?php var_dump($article) ?>` возвращает все атрибуты, но они пустые ... почему не передается значение в форму ?

Comment: А выведите просто текстом и посмотрите, вывелось что-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Попробуйте вывести значение $article в контроллере, в самом начале метода edit() с помощью dd($article):

```
public function edit(Article $article){
    $user=auth()->user(); // ?
    dd($article);
    return view('user.edit',[
        'article' => $article,
        'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
        'delimiter' => ''
    ]);
}
```

2 Странные у Вас Роуты. Ничего не утверждаю, но я не видел роутов с тремя параметрами. И метод для update у Вас вроде path. Попробуйте заменить роуты:

```
Route::get('/home/edit/{article}','Controller_Article_parents@edit')->name('edit')
Route::patch('/home/update/{article}','Controller_Article_parents@update')->name('update');
```

3 Ну и в качестве придирки*)): зачем Вам получать $user в edit(), если Вы его не используете?

Comment: и еще 5 копеек оффтопом, если можно: в качестве рекомендации есть соглашения сообщества о наименовании: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8.

Comment: Они могут быть с тремя параметрами для match. Но да, в этом случае у ТС явно какие-то беды с прочтением документации.